# Swift: update datas and screen change

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in swift but I don't understand how to do.

In my app in swift, I have the possibility to create an activity. When the user click on the save button, the savefunction is : `ref.child("Activities").child(activityID).setValue(["PDG" : userID, "Type": type, "Place": place, "AvaiblePlaces": avaiblePlaces, "Schedule": schedule])` to write in database.

So, I need to write on the DB and change screen.
The problem is on the click, the screen change but the data are not updated but the datas on firebase are updated).

Do you have a way to update before the database and after change the screen?

Comment: Could you give more information please ? Like code that show the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.